# Hotel reservation system with discounts and deposits

Tags: sql, mysql, finance

I'm making a hotel reservation app that has the following features:

Promo Codes:

The guest can choose to pay half a certain percent of the `total_amount` or the entire `total_amount`. I want to use stripe, PayPal and authorize.net as payment gateways.

Reservations are stored here:

```
CREATE TABLE `reservations` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `guest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `currency` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USD',
 `accommodation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `from_date` date NOT NULL,
 `to_date` date NOT NULL,
 `guests` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `total_amount` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `deposit_amount` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `remaining_amount` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
 `isDeposit` enum('true','false') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
 `promo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

An example reservation:

```
id|user_id  | guest_id  | currency  | accommodation_id  | from_date  | to_date        | guests  | total_amount  | deposit_amount | remaining_amount 
2 | 4       | 10        | USD       | 55                | 2015-07-02 | 2015-07-04     | 20      | 200           | 20             | 180              

| isDeposit | promo_id | paid 
| true      | 2        | 0
```

Payments are stored here:

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `reservation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `method` enum('stripe','paypal','authorize') NOT NULL,
 `type` enum('deposit','total','remaining') NOT NULL,
 `reference` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

If the guest pays that `deposit_amount` of 20 using stripe:

```
id | reservation_id | method | type     |  reference        |
1  | 2              | stripe | deposit  | 56544564545       |
```

and pays the remaining of 180 using PayPal:

```
id | reservation_id | method | type           | reference    |
1  | 2              | paypal | remaining      | 68985578474  |
```

then I will make column `paid` to 1 in reservations table.

How does this look to you?

Comment: "Promo Codes The guest can choose to pay half a certain percent of the total_amount or the entire total_amount" Can you reformulate that? Why would a guest choose to pay more?

Answer (score 3):

Not a full & detailed answer but some initial thoughts.

Some of the fields in the `reservations` table look decidedly non-normalised - `remaining_amount`, `isDeposit` and `paid`. Shouldn't these be derived from the `payments` table when needed for a view or a query? Otherwise, when you receive a payment you would also have to update at least two of these fields. Are you planning on using triggers for these updates?

If you want to keep the `isDeposit` field, then think carefully how you use it. Does it tell you that *only* a deposit has been paid so it gets set to 0 once the full amount is paid? Or does it tell you that the guest initially paid a deposit so it gets set to 1 when the deposit is paid and then gets left?

What happens when a reservation gets cancelled? There is no `status` field and presumably you cannot delete the record (and any `payments` records)?

You've also got `user_id`, `guest_id` and `guests` fields. If you want the user to enter names of any guests for the reservation you will need another structure.